# This stylesheet cannot be viewed because its source is in a different domain than the page - ie9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Getting this error for a couple of css included.

This is exactly how they have been included in the html
[link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/editor.css" media="all" ]

The files are in the same folder as the folder css which has all the css files.

Its working fine for other browsers...

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Can you show us some code, specifically the `<link>` element you use to load the stylesheets?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/editor.css" media="all" />

Comment: this is how all the css files have been included..

Comment: I am not authorized to show the full code, it is unavailable on the internet.

Comment: Are these stylesheets added using JS or jQuery? Do they load resources from another domain (e.g. using `@import`)?

Comment: Nope... Simple inclusion of CSS... Looks like a bug to me...

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this in IE10 even if I load the IE9 style sheet.  Found a solution:

1. Go to Windows Explorer where your html file is kept,
2. Right click > properties > There should be a Security message stating that the file is from another computer.....with an "Unblock" button.
3. Click Unblock.... problem solved. Style sheet is now recognized.

Comment: You saved my day, I was so in a hurry that I didn't even see what the message was. Does anyone has an explanation for this or remember what the message was?